# How to get data from web api using asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I created my first project in ASP.net.
I created the ASP.Net Web Application project and selected Empty.
I have created many pages in it, also have some pages which fetch data from my SQL server database.
Now I am required to fetch data from Web API, how can I do this? I looked up videos and other help documents, and I see many results showing how to get data for web forms applications, or MVC or web API, but not what I am looking for. Can someone please guide me on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If the Web API that you are calling does not need any key then following is the sample that accesses yahoo finance API that returns JSON and the data is then put into data table. I have not shown here some JSON classes just for the simplicity. These are getting used when i parse the JSON output from API. If you need an example for API with key, you will have to add it as one of the attribute in the URL. Let me know if you need example with API key as well.

```js
        public DataTable GetQuote(string symbol)
        {
            DataTable resultDataTable = null;
            try
            {
                string webservice_url = "";
                WebResponse wr;
                Stream receiveStream = null;
                StreamReader reader = null;
                //DataRow r;

                //https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/HDFC.BO?range=1m&interval=1m&indicators=quote&timestamp=true
                webservice_url = string.Format(StockManager.urlGlobalQuote, symbol);

                Uri url = new Uri(webservice_url);
                var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
                webRequest.Method = "GET";
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                wr = webRequest.GetResponseAsync().Result;
                receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
                reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream);

                resultDataTable = getQuoteTableFromJSON(reader.ReadToEnd(), symbol);
                reader.Close();
                if (receiveStream != null)
                    receiveStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                if (resultDataTable != null)
                {
                    resultDataTable.Clear();
                    resultDataTable.Dispose();
                }
                resultDataTable = null;
            }
            return resultDataTable;
        }

        public DataTable getQuoteTableFromJSON(string record, string symbol)
        {
            DataTable resultDataTable = null;

            if (record.ToUpper().Contains("NOT FOUND"))
            {
                return null;
            }
            DateTime myDate;
            double close;
            double high;
            double low;
            double open;
            int volume;
            double change;
            double changepercent;
            double prevclose;
            //double adjusetedClose = 0.00;
            //string formatedDate;
            var errors = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(record, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate,
                    Error = delegate (object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
                    {
                        errors.Add(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
                        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                        //args.ErrorContext.Handled = false;
                    }
                    //Converters = { new IsoDateTimeConverter() }

                });

                Chart myChart = myDeserializedClass.chart;

                Result myResult = myChart.result[0];

                Meta myMeta = myResult.meta;

                Indicators myIndicators = myResult.indicators;

                //this will be typically only 1 row and quote will have list of close, high, low, open, volume
                Quote myQuote = myIndicators.quote[0];

                //this will be typically only 1 row and adjClose will have list of adjClose
                //Adjclose myAdjClose = null;
                //if (bIsDaily)
                //{
                //    myAdjClose = myIndicators.adjclose[0];
                //}

                if (myResult.timestamp != null)
                {
                    resultDataTable = new DataTable();

                    resultDataTable.Columns.Add("Symbol", typeof(string));
                    resultDataTable.Columns.Add("Open", typeof(decimal));
                    resultDataTable.Columns.Add("High", typeof(decimal));
                    resultDataTable.Columns.Add("Low", typeof(decimal));
                    resultDataTable.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
                    resultDataTable.Columns.Add("Volume", typeof(int));
                    resultDataTable.Columns.Add("latestDay", typeof(DateTime));
                    resultDataTable.Columns.Add("previousClose", typeof(decimal));
                    resultDataTable.Columns.Add("change", typeof(decimal));
                    resultDataTable.Columns.Add("changePercent", typeof(decimal));

                    for (int i = 0; i < myResult.timestamp.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if ((myQuote.close[i] == null) && (myQuote.high[i] == null) && (myQuote.low[i] == null) && (myQuote.open[i] == null)
                            && (myQuote.volume[i] == null))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        //myDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(myResult.timestamp[i]).ToLocalTime();
                        myDate = convertUnixEpochToLocalDateTime(myResult.timestamp[i], myMeta.timezone);

                        //myDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(myResult.timestamp[i]);
                        //string formatedDate = myDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        //formatedDate = myDate.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM");

                        //myDate = System.Convert.ToDateTime(myResult.timestamp[i]);

                        //if all are null do not enter this row

                        if (myQuote.close[i] == null)
                        {
                            close = 0.00;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //close = (double)myQuote.close[i];
                            close = System.Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.00}", myQuote.close[i]));
                        }

                        if (myQuote.high[i] == null)
                        {
                            high = 0.00;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //high = (double)myQuote.high[i];
                            high = System.Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.00}", myQuote.high[i]));
                        }

                        if (myQuote.low[i] == null)
                        {
                            low = 0.00;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //low = (double)myQuote.low[i];
                            low = System.Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.00}", myQuote.low[i]));
                        }

                        if (myQuote.open[i] == null)
                        {
                            open = 0.00;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //open = (double)myQuote.open[i];
                            open = System.Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.00}", myQuote.open[i]));
                        }
                        if (myQuote.volume[i] == null)
                        {
                            volume = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            volume = (int)myQuote.volume[i];
                        }
                        prevclose = System.Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.00}", myMeta.chartPreviousClose));
                        change = close - prevclose;
                        changepercent = (change / prevclose) * 100;
                        change = System.Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.00}", change));
                        changepercent = System.Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.00}", changepercent));

                        resultDataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                                                                    symbol,
                                                                    Math.Round(open, 4),
                                                                    Math.Round(high, 4),
                                                                    Math.Round(low, 4),
                                                                    Math.Round(close, 4),
                                                                    volume,
                                                                    myDate,
                                                                    Math.Round(prevclose, 4),
                                                                    Math.Round(change, 4),
                                                                    Math.Round(changepercent, 4)
                                                                    //adjusetedClose
                                                                });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                if (resultDataTable != null)
                {
                    resultDataTable.Clear();
                    resultDataTable.Dispose();
                }
                resultDataTable = null;
            }
            return resultDataTable;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Vinay. My API needs a key. How do I add the Web API functionality to my Empty ASP.Net application? I am watching some videos, and I cannot see the Models, App_Start and other folders in my soultion explorer. Is it because I selected "Empty" and didnt select any other options of WebForm, MVC or Web API? This is a login page basically which will fetch the logged in user's basic info using the api. I am using Visual studio 2022 with C#

Comment: Not sure i understand your comment. But at some point you will need to add a web form and make it default. So that when you run, this form is shown. Just for testing purpose you can add the WebAPI call in the Page_Load() of this web form. You will also need to add dependencies with 'using'. The IDE should point that out.

Comment: Vinay, I mean when I was creating my project, I selected Empty template, and did not select any of the check boxes under "Add references"- WebForm, WebAPI or MVC,i was following one youtube video and working along.Now I am clueless how to add the WebAPI functionality to this project

Comment: If its WebAPI, you do not need to add any reference, as long as it is exposed via URL access, which is normally the case. Just add a web form and refer to specific WebAPI that your want to call. They would specific the URL including mandatory and optional parameters it requires. Refer to my example, where I am replacing place holder values in the URL with specific values and then calling the URL

Comment: Ok..i added the web form, it has a login form, which i use to login with our college login username and pssword. the login works fine, Now using web api i want to display some basic info of the logged in user, using a token key. Can you please let me know a simple way to do this? i can see lots of methods and confused which one suits mine.

Comment: Can you provide an example with API key please